# App shown in "Open in.." menu as "Copy to MyApp"

Tags: ios, cocoa, cfbundledocumenttypes

Recently, I was working on showing my app in "Open in..." menu when opening custom mail attachment (let's say filename-extension is `xyz`, and I've declared custom mime-type `application/xyz`). I followed guide on this site:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html

and my app is now displayed between all other apps, when I tap on corresponding attachment. The problem is in description under my app. Instead of just showing its name (`MyApp`) it's shown as `Copy to MyApp`.
Is there any way to make my app description not contain `Copy to`
 words?

Update, here are my app info screens:
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the configuration in your .plist?

Comment: thx, updated my answer

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue by now? From the looks (and votes) of it, other people are running into this too. Are you still a SO member?

Comment: Hi, I haven't managed it unfortunatelly. Of course I did all the stuff that @MarkHim proposed, but nothing worked for me. Only thing I've noticed is that on different OS version menu was shown properly as "Open in..", without any changes in code.

Answer (score 6):

Your app will always show with "Copy to" using this method and "Open in..". No amount of tweaking the settings will change that.

What you want to do instead is create a Share extension. The steps for that are well documented by Apple. See for example: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/

A Share extension changes the nature of your app's interaction. Instead of responding to openURL in your app delegate, you create a share extension which deals with (possibly several files) as it sees fit.

Comment: Hi, I have return Share Extension. Is there a way to remove "Copy to MyApp" in "open in" menu?

Answer (score 3):

CFBundleTypeRole doesn’t works with iOS. Menu name is simply depends on LSHandlerRank.

Here is result on my test.

```
Owner: Copy to [MyApp]
Alternate, Default: Import with [MyApp]
None: No appearance
(tested in iOS 10.3.1)
```

Farther usage are detailed in CoreFoundationKeys reference.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685

If you want to use custom menu name, you can achieve this with Share extension as @Dale said.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a pretty old question, but if you set LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace to true in your Info.plist, and then properly handle the results of that, iOS will show "Open In" instead of "Copy To" as long as the source app supports this.

See here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW13

and here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationopenurloptionsopeninplacekey

and here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417051-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso

**Update**

Note that I see "Open In" when I browse a file of my file type from inside the iOS Files app. In Dropbox, I see "Copy To". I assume that the Files app sets some setting that Dropbox doesn't when showing the "Open In" sheet. Have you tried to open one of your files from the Files app after setting this setting?

Comment: That makes total sense but for me at least adding LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace = true didn't change the appearance of the app in the share sheet. It still says "Copy to…". Even after a delete/reinstall of the app.

Comment: Same here, were you able to figure this out?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can't just set the Info.plist value to true. You also have to implement support for the different way of opening files that doing that introduces. However, it does seem odd that after changing the value, it still showed the old text. I'm not sure what it up.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the `LSHandlerRank` in your `.plist` to `Owner`

`Owner` signalizes that yours is the native app that creates and opens files of this type.

**Update**
Try setting the `CFBundleTypeRole` to `Viewer`

> [...] "Viewer" role for your document type, [...] means that your application can open and read a particular file format, but can not save in this file format. [Post on MacOSX Guru Site](http://www.macosxguru.net/article.php?story=20040914192656471)

I could imagine that you are not allowed to edit the actual files that are attached to an E-Mail anyway.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, but I've tried it before (double checked it while ago) and it isn't solving my problem.

Comment: Did you remove and install the app, and delete the DerivedData folder / cleaned buildFolder after you tried?

Comment: Does not change anything for me either, unfortunately (even after re-installing the app).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add below line in **info.plist** file to fix this problem.

```
 Supports opening documents in place : YES
```

[image]